# Stanford Collapsed Dependency parser error: loadmodel

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, netbeans-7, stanford-nlp

I want to get the Stanford's Collapsed Dependency parser. So here's my code:

```
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.Sentence;
import edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import java.util.List;

class Parser{
public static void main(String[] args) {
            LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
            lp.setOptionFlags(new String[] { "-maxLength", "80","-retainTmpSubcategories" });
            String[] sent = { "This", "is", "an", "easy", "sentence", "." };
            List<CoreLabel> rawWords = Sentence.toCoreLabelList(sent);
            Tree parse = lp.apply(rawWords);
            parse.pennPrint();
            System.out.println();

            TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
            GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
            GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(parse);
            List<TypedDependency> tdl = gs.typedDependenciesCCprocessed();
            System.out.println(tdl);
            TreePrint tp = new TreePrint("penn,typedDependenciesCollapsed");
            tp.printTree(parse);
            }
```

}

I get the following errors for the following 2 codes when run in Netbeans.

For,

```
LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
```

the error message I get is:

```
 cannot find symbol, symbol: method loadModel(java.lang.String), location: class.LexicalizedParser lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel("edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz"); "
```

And for

```
lp.setOptionFlags(new String[] { "-maxLength", "80","-retainTmpSubcategories" });
```

the following error message is shown.

```
setOptionFlags(java.lang.String..)is not public in edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser; cannot be accessed from outside package.
```

I have imported "stanford-corenlp-1.3.0.jar". How can I fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this with Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2?

The latest download can be found here:

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml